# how can I run code in jsFiddle with out tags html,body,script inside the html window

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have  [Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/Vdht5/4/) I want to remove from the window html:

1 - tags as a html,body, (like `<html class="no-js" lang="en">` ) **class="no-js"** inside tag html.

2 -  i have jQuery code like:

```
$(function(){

      SyntaxHighlighter.all();

    });

    $(window).load(function(){

      $('.flexslider').flexslider({

        animation: "slide",

        start: function(slider){

          $('body').removeClass('loading');

        }

      });

    });
```

and try to move it to window of js but then the code not work well.

how can I leave clean code on the html window?

Thankue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the HTML pane you can keep only the content inside div (you can safely remove `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<body>` tags)
2. Put your jQuery code inside the JS window (`<script>` tag is not necessary).
3. Change the drop down selector option in the left side of "Choose Framework" section to `onDomReady` (instead of `onLoad`)